# CSS - Can't resolve local ttf file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

Alright, common issue - just trying to include a custom font. Ive tried multiple methods, including:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: SequelSansBlackDisp;
    src:"./src/resources/SequelSansBlackDisp.ttf";
}
@font-face {
    font-family: SequelSansLightDisp;
    src:"./src/resources/SequelSansLightDisp.ttf";
}
```

and

```
@font-face {
    font-family: SequelSansBlackDisp;
    src:url("./src/resources/SequelSansBlackDisp.ttf");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: SequelSansLightDisp;
    src:url("./src/resources/SequelSansLightDisp.ttf");
}
```

To no avail. The first doesnt do anything, while the 2nd draws "cannot resolve" errors. The font is right there in the resources folder - I did rename the ttf file to take out the spaces. Maybe this is the issue? How would I know how to correctly reference the ttf file?

Comment: The `font-family` name must be the same as the one embedded in the file (metadata), it's not necessarily the same as the file name. On windows10 you can right click the file name and hit Preview, it will bring up a dialogue and at the top give you the `Font Name`.

Comment: font-family name in quotes and make sure your relative path is ../ not ./

Comment: For reference, here is the stylesheet generated by the google fonts service for the Roboto font, note the differences - https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap

Answer (score 0):

try this solution:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: fontName;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  url('/static/fonts/dir/font_name.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: SequelSansBlackDisp;
    src:url('./src/resources/SequelSansBlackDisp.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: SequelSansLightDisp;
    src: url('./src/resources/SequelSansLightDisp.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: I still get the Can't resolve './src/resources/SequelSansBlackDisp.ttf' error

Comment: Look at the font path, is it correct? Use lowercase letters for the font URL. Uppercase letters can give unexpected results in IE!